# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter to ignore millisecond and zone

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, java-time, datetime-parsing

I am struggling with Java 8 `DateTimeFormatter`.

I would like to convert a given `String` to dateFormat and parse to `LocalDateTime`

Here is my code

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
String text = "2020-01-01T01:01:11.123Z"
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(text, f)
```

But Java throws

> Text could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19

If I change `ofPattern` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`, my code executes without any error.
But I don’t want to use millisecond and time zone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
String text = "2020-01-01T01:01:11.123Z";
LocalDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(text)
                                  .toLocalDateTime();
```

To get rid of the milliseconds information, do:

```
LocalDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(text)
                                  .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
                                  .toLocalDateTime();
```

You can also use `OffsetDateTime` in place of `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Good answer. I recommend `OffsetDateTime` since we have an offset ( `Z`) and no time zone (a time zone is a place on Earth and all the historic and known future changes to UTC offset in that place).